# Cannot access SWITCH thru VPN

Tags: vpn, switch, netgear

I've VPN connection set up that i connect to company with. I can connect to all devices (other switches, routers, servers from same subnet with same settings just diffrent ip) but I can't connect to NetGear Router GS748Tv3.

Settings on switch:

- IP address 192.168.1.8
- Subnet mask 255.255.255.0
- Default gateway 192.168.1.1
- Management VLAN ID: 0 (1 - 4094 or 0) (0 means all VLANs)

Switch has 2 VLAN's configured 1 and 2.

I can access this switch thru VPN if i log in to server and from server to switch but this is a little bit slower then normal way.

Anything I'm missing?

**EDIT:**

Router in location has IP - 192.168.1.1 and it's only gateway to internet. So far there's no additional network besides 192.168.1.0/24. Switch has 2 VLAN's but only one VLAN has connected cables to it and network on that VLAN is 192.168.1.0/24.

I can ping 192.168.1.8 (ip of switch) while being on site but i can't ping/access it thru VPN.

VPN assigns IP's from same subnet as local DHCP does (it's Draytek Vigor 2930 working as DHCP for local network and VPN at same time - so it's all in one device).

Comment: Need more info about where you are trying to connect from.

For instance, if you are in 10.10.10.x/24 and try to reach 192.168.1.8/24, you need to create a tunnel between both. The default gateway for switch IP can be different from default gateways for those two vlan's on that netgear box.

Answer (score 1):

does the switch 'know' how to route traffic to you? [eg does 192.168.1.1 know how to forward packets back to you sitting 'behind' the vpn?].

some manageable devices allow administrative access only from same subnet or only from selected subnets - is your ip ['behind' the vpn] allowed?

Comment: This is my IP on VPN 192.168.1.134, Mask 255.255.255.255, Gateway is empty... I would understand this being the case but why all other managable switches (like Linksys) allow me to log in to them?

Comment: What is the gateway on your actual LAN connection? Is it also 192.168.1.1?

Comment: @madboy - does your vpn SNATs your connections directly on some local ip? it seems that 192.168.1.234/32 overlaps with your lan - 192.168.1.0/24. a picture with addresses, vpn, netmasks, routes would be helpful.

Comment: See my update of question